# Programming CC3200 Microcontroller and Separate Flash Without a Development Board

Tags: microcontroller, usb, wifi, texas-instruments, programmer

I have an "Alfie" device which has wifi and USB, but I never
use this device, so would like to change its function.

It uses the CC3200 microcontroller (which has a little ROM)
and a separate flash chip.  At first, I thought I could just
reprogram the flash chip alone and make it more useful, but
it seems to have encryption forcing the reprogramming to
go through the CC3200, so now I am hoping I can use a
SPI (or UART) programmer applied to the CC3200 with some
jumpers to reprogram it (I'm guessing the original developers
would reprogram this chip with just an SPI programmer, or
even simpler with the USB port, and a few jumpers, right?).
Can I do this with just a generic programmer?  All the instructions
online seem to do this with a particular development board;
I don't understand why Texas Instruments would not publish
a bare-minimum programming spec.

So, how can I most easily get a new compiled "mcuimg.bin" onto this device?

By the way, I also looked for back doors, but my computer sees
no USB connection and, though the wifi gateway listens on port 80,
every page I asked for returns "404 Not Found".

Here are some photos:
https://fccid.io/document.php?id=2971294

Comment: The link to photos is broken. What exactly is *IT* ? https://www.ti.com/tool/CC3200-LAUNCHXL  ? What code do you want to download into the CC3200 ? What programmer ?

Comment: @GrahamStevenson Photo link still works for me.  A simple LED blink code is fine to get me started.  I'd like to burn it with just a CH340 and jumpers.  This all seems possible from the datasheets/docs, but every online reference I find uses a development board, so I'm not sure.

Comment: it's probably programmed using a JTAG programmer

Comment: @vicatcu It can be programmed with JTAG, but I instead used the simpler FTDI/CH340 serial programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texas Instruments does provide the programming software for free: UniFlash and Code Composer Studio.  All I needed to buy was a cheap $2 FTDI programmer (not the entire Texas Instruments development board).  It takes a while to debug things but, in the end, I was able to run all tutorials and construct my own flood wifi alarm.